# Add space in paragraph

Tags: spacing

I want space in paragraph

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{$\bullet$ \textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ } %if you want a name write it as \chapter{name}
init
\section{seccion}
Vamos a empezar organizándonos. Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es elegir el tipo de documento, empezando por preguntarnos si es un documento corto o largo ya que el formato del documento varía en gran medida según su longitud:
\paragraph{Documentos cortos:} para ellos usaremos la clase article y sus derivadas, como scrartcl de las clases KOMA. Como norma general este tipo de documentos tienen 5 niveles de títulosAprendimos a usar los diferentes niveles de título cuando escribimos nuestro primer documento (section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph), con los tres primeros numerados, y no llevan portada. 

this is not paragraph (
and should not have a bullet)
\section{ seccion}
 \end{document}
```

some this result:

[image]

Comment: use `\vspace{1em}` to add some vertical space. Change 1em by  a bigger or smaller number to modify the spacing.

Comment: @santimirandarp i need example please

Comment: you have asked multiple questions now all basically asking the same thing, it would be better just to have one question and edit/clarify it as needed. It isn't clear why you want to redefne the standard `\paragraph` command in this incompatible way rather than use the standard `itemize` environment for bulleted indented paragraphs?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is right, but when use paragraph?

Comment: I do not understand your question, sorry. The standard `\paragraph` command is a sectioning command in the hierarchy chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph  like all sectioning commands it can be numbered, it prevents page breajks after the heading, can enter text in the table of contents etc, your definition undoes all that. The output you show is the layout of the itemize environment

Answer (score 1):

The layout you want appears to be that of `itemnize`

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ } %if you want a name write it as \chapter{name}
init
\section{seccion}
Vamos a empezar organizándonos. Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es elegir el tipo de documento, empezando por preguntarnos si es un documento corto o largo ya que el formato del documento varía en gran medida según su longitud:
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Documentos cortos:} para ellos usaremos la clase article y sus derivadas, como scrartcl de las clases KOMA. Como norma general este tipo de documentos tienen 5 niveles de títulosAprendimos a usar los diferentes niveles de título cuando escribimos nuestro primer documento (section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph), con los tres primeros numerados, y no llevan portada. 

\end{itemize}

this is not paragraph (and should not have a bullet)
\section{ seccion}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: and if I want to put other items in the item, would not it be a problem?

Comment: you can have any number of `\item` in an itemize list @x-rw

Comment: with your first item I want to pretend that it is a paragraph with a bullet, or should I use the paragraph tag?

Comment: @x-rw sorry I have no idea what you mean by that? `\paragraph` is unrelated to paragraphs it is just the name of the level 4 section heading command.